# Naming convention for speed variables/columns

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm importing a large set of speed data and trying to figure out how to best rename the columns without loosing essential descriptive data. I generally use underscores to separate so "SpeedZone 3m/s (Distance) (m)" to "SpeedZone_3m_s_Distance_m)" isn't an issue, but I'm not sure how to address some of the special cases outlined below:

Speed designation "m/s"
Greater than or equal to ">="
Negative numbers "-"
Seconds squared "m/s²"

Sample data. I can write a function to substitute the characters - I'm looking for thoughts on what to rename to such as "m/s" can be changed to "m_per_s". Thanks.

```
column_names <- c("SpeedZone 3m/s (Distance) (m)",
                  "SpeedZone >=3m/s (Distance) (m)",
                  "SpeedBand1 Band1 (1.0-3.0 m/s)(Distance) (m)",
                  "SpeedBand1 >= Band1 (1.0-3.0 m/s) (Distance) (m)",
                  "Decel Zone -6 to -5m/s²",
                  "Accel Zone 5-6m/s²")
~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to convert `>=` into something that works in a C-style identifier? I'd use `ge`, same as Perl and test.

Comment: I’m looking to see if there are conventions/suggestions on how to keep special characters that are typically frowned upon to use in variables so that I don’t have to resort to using a variable such as SpeedZone_greater_than_or_equal_to_3m_s_Distance_m